# Conditional statement within react render meth

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I am new to react and I am trying to add a condition within the render method so that if the value `framework1` is empty I need not add a text within the HTML.

Below is my code.

```
buildResults = () => {
 const {
results
} = this.state;

return {
  <div className={`${block}__results`}>
   <table>
    <thead></thead>
<tbody>
   { results.map(item => this.buildResult(item)) }
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
}


buildResult = (data) => {
  const {
   framework1,
   framework2
} = data;

return (
 <tr className={`${block}__row`}>
   <td className={`${block}__cell ${block}__cell--ticker`}>
/* I need to display the text "view" only if framework1 is not empty */
   <a href={`${framework1}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">View</a>
</td>
</tr>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an if statement to check whether the there is data, in this case, I am checking whether the data in `framework1` is a string.

```
buildResults = () => {
 const {
results
} = this.state;

return {
  <div className={`${block}__results`}>
   <table>
    <thead></thead>
<tbody>
   { results.map(item => this.buildResult(item)) }
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
}


buildResult = (data) => {
  const {
   framework1,
   framework2
} = data;

return (
 <tr className={`${block}__row`}>
   <td className={`${block}__cell ${block}__cell--ticker`}>
   if (framework1.indexOf("ST1") ){
     // display something else
   }
   else {
     <a href={`${framework1}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">View</a>
   }
</td>
</tr>
)
}
```